# firefox bug with history

Tags: linux, firefox

I noticed the following unwanted behaviour (bug) on the latest firefox for linux:

1. go to youtube.com
2. click on "trending"
3. click on any video (the first one for example).
4. click on the firefox 'go back' button

bug=> the 'go forward' button disappears.

This bug comes for firefox since it also occurs with all plugins disabled.

ps: To reproduce this bug on windows, you can change the user-agent of your firefox to a linux one so that youtube gives you the same page as the one when the bug is present. To do that:

1. download the 'modify headers' firefox plugin
2. open the preferences of this plugin
3. click on select actions->modify
4. in the first box, type User-Agent.
5. in the second box, type for example Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3.3; Linux 2.6.8-gentoo-r3; X11;
6. click on 'add', and then 'start'.
7. Don't forget to remove all your firefox cookies, by going to preferences->privacy->remove individual cookies->search for youtube and delete them all.

Is that normal ? Do you experience it too ? Any idea how to prevent this unwanted behaviour from happening ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not log this bug in BugZilla?

Comment: I wanted to be sure it was indeed a bug and someone else was experiencing too, and no easy solution could be found to fix it.